# A question about how far projective geometry can be extended

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Is there a natural way to extend or embed a separable and infinite-dimensional real Hilbert space H
into a "projective space" (i.e. a space which is "infinite-dimensional" and satisfies some standard
version of the axioms of projective geometry.)? In other words, is there an "infinite-dimensional"
analogue of the situation in which finite-dimensional Euclidean spaces can be considered to be
sub-spaces of projective spaces of the same dimension? If such an "infinite-dimensional" projective
space can exist would it's topology necessarily make it non-metrizable?

Comment: Do you mean this by any chance? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_Hilbert_space

Comment: Thanks alot for your response. It is exactly what I was looking for
and it answers my second question also. It seems that a "projective
Hilbert space" can not only exist but can be metrizable as well.
